# Difference of two largest values from a set of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

I have a set of i.i.d. random variables $(E_1, \ldots, E_N)$ that are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$.

I guess, if $E_1$ lives in $(S,\mathcal{S},\mathbb{P})$, then the whole set lives in $(S^N,\bigotimes_{j=1}^N\mathcal{S},\mathbb{P}^N)$.
I define $\Omega = S^N$.

Now, for a realization $\omega \in \Omega$, let $k_1(\omega)$ be the index such that $E_{k_1} (\omega)$ is the largest value from $(E_1(\omega), \ldots, E_N(\omega))$, and $k_2(\omega)$ the index such that $E_{k_2} (\omega)$ is the second largest value.

My question is: What is the distribution/density of $E_{k_1} - E_{k_2}$?

Well, I read in Gumbel's *Statistics of extremes* that if $\rho (x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is the density of the $E$'s, then $E_{k_1}$ itself has a density

$N\rho (x) F(x)^{N-1}$

with $F$ being the cumulative function, i.e. $F(x) = \int_0^x \rho(y) dy$. This seems plausible to me.

The density for $E_{k_2}$ itself is

$N(N-1)\rho (x) (1- F(x)) F(x)^{N-2}$.

Usually, I determine the densities of sums and differences of *independent* random variables by Fourier or Laplace transform.

My problem is, that when I want to compute the density of $E_{k_1} - E_{k_2}$, then I have to take care about the dependecies of both values - and I do not know how.

Can anybody help?

Comment: i.e. given a sample of size $n$: if $X_{(n)}$ denotes the largest order statistic and $X_{(n-1)}$ is the second largest, you want the pdf of $X_{(n)} - X_{(n-1)}$. For a neat manual derivation, I suspect the memoryless property will show its hand.

Comment: Yes, I hope that. But an ansatz would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \sim Exponential(\lambda)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Let $X_n$ denote the largest order statistic, and $X_{n-1}$ the second largest.

Then, the joint pdf of $(X_{n-1}, X_n)$ is, say, $g(x_{n-1}, x_n)$:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the calculation.

We seek the cdf of $Y = X_n - X_{n-1}$, i.e. $P(Y<y)$, which is:

[image]

which is the cdf of an Exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. All done.

**Notes**

1. For a neat manual derivation, I suspect the memoryless property will show its hand.
2. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors of the software used.

Comment: Thanks, that helps for a start! One question: Can you explain to get to the order statistics of $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ without using Mathematica? I mean, the line in Out[2] looks similar to the formula I found for $E_{k_2}$: The $n(n-1)$ comes from combinatorics, the $\lambda^2$ from the densities. The term with the exponent $n-2$ is also clear: That is the probability that the $n-2$ other values are smaller than $x_{n-1}$. Does that work?

Comment: For a discussion on how to derive the _joint pdf_ of 2 (or more) order statistics, see p.12 of _Order Statistics_ by David and Nagaraja (third edition). You can also find the formula on the wiki page at:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution